# Reverse Engineering vs. decompiling

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I am thinking about learning assembly language in order to gain expertise in reverse engineering malwares. My question is that whether it is worthwhile to learn assembly language for reverse engineering when there are sophisticated decompilers available in the market (decompiler from hex-rays is very good, from what I heard).

Granted that decompilation does not reproduce the original code but it still reduces the complexity of understanding the code in assembly language. So, are there any strong reasons for attempting to reverse engineer by looking at the assembly code?

Thanks.

Comment: To reverse-engineer malware, you should be pretty good at assembly. I knew a guy that could read asm faster than I can read C.

Comment: Assembly code is the least of your worries. I could could teach my little sister assembly. The biggest problems are deciphering the control flow and data flow. Anyway if you're serious about this, just learn assembly. To reverse your question, why would you *avoid* learning assembly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to know assembly language pretty well to reverse engineer malware. 
For starters, people who write malware are pretty good in blocking decompilers. 
Also, if original code is written in assembly it will not decompile well into high level source. Especially if it is well optimized.

Comment: It will not decompile at all, most probably.

Comment: also, if it decompiles, the result might win the next International Obfuscated C Code Contest.

Answer (score 5):

It is absolutely necessary that you learn assembly for this. Although decompilers (hex-rays) are very good at adding understanding the majority of self-modifying and encoded malware contains decoders that are written in assembly to begin with. It is therefore very difficult to decompile it to a higher level language.